# autocomplete plugin loading icon sometimes dosent stop spinning when it should

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm working with the autocomplete plugin from Jquery UI. I have a small graphic that spins, everything works fine as long as a match is found and selected. My problem is that if no results are found or the focus moves the graphic still is visible and spins. If no results are found it also just keeps spinning and the not found message is never displayed.

Code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```js
var _autocomp = {
            source: function(request, response, event) {

                var url = "@Url.Content("~/Jobs/Users")";
                $.getJSON(url, { prefixText: request.term }, function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, Profile) {

                        response($.map(data, function(Profile) {
                            var name = Profile.ID + " - " + Profile.Name;
                            return {
                                label: name,
                                value: Profile.ID
                            };
                        }));
                    });


                });



            },

            minLength: 3,
            delay: 50,
            error:function() {
                $(this).removeClass('loader');
            },
            failure: function() {
                $(this).removeClass('loader');
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                this.value = ui.item.label;
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).removeClass('loader');
            },
            response: function(event, ui) {
                if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                    $(this).text("No results found");
                } else {
                    $(this).empty();
                }

            },
            search: function (e, u) {
                $(this).addClass('loader');
            },
            open:function() {
                $(this).removeClass('loader');
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {
                if (!ui.item) {

                    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                        valid = false;

                    $('.employeeAutoComp').children("option").each(function () {


                        if ($(this).text().match(matcher)) {
                            this.selected = valid = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    if (!valid) { // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                        $(this).val("");
                        $('.employeeAutoComp').val("");
                        //input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
        };

        $('.employeeAutoComp').autocomplete(_autocomp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try remove class "loader" and display message in complete() method. I found if there is no results match, complete method is called. I have a similar issue please see [jQuery UI ui-autocomplete-loading spinner not stopping/disappear when found results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43119612/jquery-ui-ui-autocomplete-loading-spinner-not-stopping-disappear-when-found-resu)