# jQuery UI ui-autocomplete-loading spinner not stopping/disappear when found results

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using JQuery UI autocomplete-loading spinner in my project by adding .ui-autocomplete-loading class. When I start typing in the editor box, the spinner shows up as expect. If there is no match results, the loading spinner disappear which indicates the search complete. But if there is a match found, the spinner is still showing, even after a selection is made. (see below pic)

[image]

My goal is to get this results: (when search complete or results found, spinner should be removed/stopped)
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Here is my example code:

View:

```
@model AutoCompleteInMVCJson.Models.City

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "www.myexample.com";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading {
        background: white url("../images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Name").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/Index",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Model

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index(string Prefix)
        {
            //Note : you can bind same list from database
            List<City> ObjList = new List<City>()
            {

                new City {Id=1,Name="Latur" },
                new City {Id=2,Name="Mumbai" },
                new City {Id=3,Name="Pune" },
                new City {Id=4,Name="Delhi" },
                new City {Id=5,Name="Dehradun" },
                new City {Id=6,Name="Noida" },
                new City {Id=7,Name="New Delhi" }

        };
            //Searching records from list using LINQ query
            var CityName = (from N in ObjList
                            where N.Name.StartsWith(Prefix)
                          select new { N.Name });
            return Json(CityName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for Curiousdev's input and after my further debugging I found a solution.

Add

```
$("#Name").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
```

in both success and complete method will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

In Ajax success method you can simply remove class from textbox using [.removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) function

```
$("#textboxid").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");
```

Comment: Hi, I added $("#Name").removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading"); in success right before response function. The behavior reversed. When there is matches found, spinner disappears. But when there is no match found, spinner is always showing.